Get an ENOTDIR Error if I want to build a Tailwindcss CSS-file
I installed Node and checked if it's up and running on my Mac. After that I created a folder with all the required files and installed and initialized Tailwindcss there. Than I did all the steps from some YouTube Tutorials. All seams fine. But If I want to build the Output CSS I'll get an Error:
npx -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/css/styles.css                                              
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/istvan/Websites/vhosts/de.iv-media/subdomains/test/src/input.css/package.json
npm ERR! errno -20
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/Users/istvan/Websites/vhosts/de.iv-media/subdomains/test/src/input.css/package.json'

Any ideas? Thanks.
I also reinstalled Node and tried some different folders, but I get same error.

I forgot to add tailwindcss to npx call. The complete call needs to be:
npx tailwindcss -i ...

